# What are the best ways to gain knowledge and become a subject matter expert in a new product

Tags: knowledge-management

I believe that majority of the business analysts needs to learn about new products, features, functionalities and domain. There may not be any major support from colleagues to explore more in a new product. So the ultimate solution is self learning. 
**Scenario**

I have joined as a product owner in a credit risk management team. i don't have any much idea about the domain and the product. They informed to learn the product within 1 month period. I have tried the below options
1. Analyses the product documentations
2. Peer level demos
But i am still struggling to get the logic behind calculations and usability

I would like to know the best methods and tips to gain knowledge without the help of others.

Comment: I may be in the minority, but I don't think "product management" is in scope.

Comment: This is a polling question, and is too broad to be answered canonically. If it can be rewritten to show what you've tried, and why that's not working for you, it may be possible for the community to reopen it.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It isn't, directly. But we do allow some Product Owner type questions, because they're part of a project management framework. But this question (as originally posted) still doesn't meet our guidelines. I agree that product management as a field is certainly out of scope, though.

Comment: Todd, I have updated my question with some changes. Can you able to help me now.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to learn something about your product is to *use* it. Not in an artificial testing situation or powerpoint presentation, but really *use it*.

Walk a mile in your user's shoes. Literally. Go where they work, and do their work for a day using your product. If you need to explain why you are there to external customers (so the people that are serviced by your customers with the help of your product) you can always just say you are new or an intern.

Not only will you better understand your users and product, you might come up with idea how to improve your product that your user's could not think about or formulate properly because they don't know what options exist.

*(As an example that I always use in those situations, I always thought the interface design of one of our apps was really badly thought out and implemented by a sloppy 5th grader, because it broke every single standard of color and size. Until I actually worked in the warehouse where they wore clumsy, protective gloves in shady lighting conditions and orange lights blinking in the background and instead of pulling of the gloves every time they used the computer, they just kept them on and needed a less sophisticated interface because it's hard to hit a normal button with the mouse when you have protective gloves on. From that point on, that user interface was pure genius in my eyes because it really worked for that situation.)*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food